# Obtaining data from a different row of data frame

Tags: r

I have a large data frame. Each row has data for a specific date. The next group of columns has stock prices. Each column represents one stock. I then have offset columns, one for each stock column. I have to offset the current row by the offset amount. Then I put the prices found in the first group of columns (but now using the offset row) in the last group of columns, which start out as NA.

For example, the value in row 1, col 3 is 1, so I need to offset the first row by 1. That gives me row 2. I need to get the price, p1, that is in row 2, col 1. That value is 2. The value 2 is then placed into row 1, col 5.

I theoretically solved the problem with a double loop, but the code was hopelessly slow. I was able to eliminate one loop. Can someone please help me eliminate the remaining loop?

Below is my code as well as the data frame before and after the code runs. Note that in the sample, I omitted the dates as they are not needed.

```
p1 = 1:1000000
p2 = 11:1000010
of1 = c(rep(1, 100000), rep(2, 800000), rep(0, 100000) )
of2 = c(rep(2,100000),rep(1,800000), rep(0, 100000) )
DF1 = data.frame(p1 = p1, p2 = p2, of1 = of1, of2 = of2)
DF1$newPrice1 = rep(NA, 1000000)
DF1$newPrice2 = rep(NA, 1000000)
head(DF1)



p1 p2 of1 of2 newPrice1 newPrice2
1  1 11   1   2        NA        NA
2  2 12   1   2        NA        NA
3  3 13   1   2        NA        NA
4  4 14   1   2        NA        NA
5  5 15   1   2        NA        NA
6  6 16   1   2        NA        NA
for(j in 1:2) {
DF1[j+4] = DF1[DF1[,j+2] + row(DF1)[,j], j]
}

head(DF1)

  p1 p2 of1 of2 newPrice1 newPrice2
1  1 11   1   2         2        13
2  2 12   1   2         3        14
3  3 13   1   2         4        15
4  4 14   1   2         5        16
5  5 15   1   2         6        17
6  6 16   1   2         7        18
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DF1$np1 <- DF1$p1[seq_along(DF1$p1) + DF1$of1]
DF1$np2 <- DF1$p2[seq_along(DF1$p2) + DF1$of2]

identical(DF1$np1, DF1$newPrice1)
#[1] TRUE

identical(DF1$np2, DF1$newPrice2)
#[1] TRUE
```